# Quotient Rings by ideals generated by irreducible polynomials

Tags: abstract-algebra

Prove that there exists a subfield $\mathbb{F}$ of $\mathbb{R}$ such that $\mathbb{F}$ is isomorphic to $Q[x]/(2x^3 -3x^2 +6)$. 
The given polynomial is Eisenstein at $3$ and hence irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$. The quotient ring is therefore a field. The polynomial has two turning points at $0$ and $1$ and it’s positive at both turning points and hence it has only one real root and two complex roots. The quotient ring is not a sub field of $\mathbb{R}$. How then can we find a sub field of $\mathbb{R}$ isomorphic to the quotient ring? Please help.

Comment: $0$ and $1$ aren't turning points, they are extremal points.

Comment: They are extremal points of course. The roots of the derivative of f(x) , aren’t they the turning points of f(x)?

Comment: No, turning points of $f$ are extremal points of $f'$. It is where $f$ turns not between pointing upwards and pointing downwards, but between convex (turning upwards) and concave (turning downwards).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\Bbb Q[x]/(2x^3-3x^2+6)$ is an extension of $\Bbb Q$ obtained by adjoining a *single root* of $2x^3-3x^2+6$ to $\Bbb Q$. It is (a priori) *not the splitting field* of $2x^3-3x^2+6$.

Which is to say, $F$ doesn't have to contain *all* the roots, just one. Some times the other roots come along for the ride automatically, but in this case, at least if you pick the right root to start with, you can find a **really** good reason (pun intended) why this won't happen.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. You have opened my eyes. All along I was under the wrong impression that the quotient ring is isomorphic to the splitting Field!!

Comment: By the by, I enjoyed your pun. Though it is complex it’s real.

Comment: @LawrenceMano For an example where all the roots come together automatically, consider primitive $n$th roots of unity. For instance, the primitive $8$th roots of unity are given, over $\Bbb Q$, by the polynomial $x^4+1$. And in $\Bbb Q[x]/(x^4+1)$, all four roots are included.

Comment: Thank you. Got it!

Answer (score 0):

Your quotient ring is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}(\sigma)$, where $\sigma$ is a root of your polynomial.

HINT:
You have three roots $\sigma_1, \sigma_2, \sigma_3$ and so $\mathbb{Q}(\sigma_1) \cong \mathbb{Q}(\sigma_2) \cong \mathbb{Q}(\sigma_3)$ and one of the roots is real.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.